# Тернарный оператор классы laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Как использовать тернарный оператор с классами?
Пытаюсь сделать вот так, не выходит:

```
$array = Cookie::get('cart') ? json_decode(Cookie::get('cart') : [];
```

Comment: Количество открывающихся и закрывающихся скобок в вашем коде не совпадает.

Comment: А что `Cookie::get('cart')` возвращает в качестве пустого значения? Если '[]' - то это не пустая строка.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh - [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/52ce8cddbb6179475ee44eca66dfdf18d4b07701)? Та и возвращает он тут json судя по коду)

Comment: А что конкретно не выходит-то? Какая-то ошибка, или код ведет себя не так как должен?

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите узнать, что вернёт  Cookie::get('cart'), то сделайте dd(Cookie::get('cart')); - получите данные, что находится в куках.
Следовательно, если там не false(0, пустая строка, пустой массив, NULL,пустая переменная), то выполнится первое условие.

Замечу, что вопрос задан неверно. Вы не используете "тернарный оператор с классами", вы используете тернарный оператор с результатом выполнения метода get класса Cookie.

То есть, чтобы вы понимали, вы не приводите к bool сам класс, а приводите  значение, которое вернёт вам метод get.